# mutate case_when and combined with or

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to create a new variable based on two conditions, for which the second condition may take two alternative values. Is there a way in the `case_when` function to combine "and" with "or" in one line of code?

Say this is the first dataframe:

```
df1 <- data.frame(company = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                 since = c(2014, 2017, 2014, 2013),
                 end = c(NA,NA,NA, 2014))
```

And this is the second:

```
df2 <- data.frame(company = c("A", "B", "C", "D",
                              "A", "B", "C", "D",
                              "A", "B", "C", "D"),
                  year = c(2013, 2013, 2013, 2013,
                           2014, 2014, 2014, 2014,
                           2015, 2015, 2015, 2015))
```

Now I want to combine the two and create a new variable based on conditions of the first dataframe. The new variable should get a score of `1` when `since` is the same or greater than `year` AND when `end` is either greater than `year` OR when `end` is `NA`.

The following code works:

```
df3 <- df2 %>% 
  left_join(df1, by = "company") %>% 
  mutate(new_var = case_when(year >= since & end > year ~ 1,
                             year >= since & is.na(end) ~ 1,
                             TRUE ~ 0)) %>% 
  select(!c(since, end))
```

And gives me:

```
   company year new_var
1        A 2013       0
2        B 2013       0
3        C 2013       0
4        D 2013       1
5        A 2014       1
6        B 2014       0
7        C 2014       1
8        D 2014       0
9        A 2015       1
10       B 2015       0
11       C 2015       1
12       D 2015       0
```

But, ideally I would want to combine this into one line of code. Something like:

```
df3 <- df2 %>% 
  left_join(df1, by = "company") %>% 
  mutate(new_var = case_when(year >= since & end > year | is.na(end) ~ 1,
                             TRUE ~ 0)) %>% 
  select(!c(since, end))
```

But this gives me:

```
   company year new_var
1        A 2013       1
2        B 2013       1
3        C 2013       1
4        D 2013       1
5        A 2014       1
6        B 2014       1
7        C 2014       1
8        D 2014       0
9        A 2015       1
10       B 2015       1
11       C 2015       1
12       D 2015       0
```

So is there a way to combine this into the same line of code? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Just a guess, try brackets: `year >= since & (end > year | is.na(end)) ~ 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap OR with brackets:

```
df2 %>% 
  left_join(df1, by = "company") %>% 
  mutate(new_var = case_when(year >= since & (end > year | is.na(end)) ~ 1,
                             TRUE ~ 0)) %>% 
  select(!c(since, end)))

#    company year new_var
# 1        A 2013       0
# 2        B 2013       0
# 3        C 2013       0
# 4        D 2013       1
# 5        A 2014       1
# 6        B 2014       0
# 7        C 2014       1
# 8        D 2014       0
# 9        A 2015       1
# 10       B 2015       0
# 11       C 2015       1
# 12       D 2015       0
```